# Evaluating a function in an expression - R

Tags: r

I am creating a custom function in R that takes another function as one of it's arguments. I want to assert that this argument takes on only a specific list of functions. The format of my code is similar to this

```
results_func <- function(func, args) {
  if (func != ranger::ranger){
       stop("The function passed  to results_func is not valid")
   }
# Other code
}
```

The error I get is

```
comparison (2) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

How can I evaluate an expression of equivalency in a function in R?